# SNOWFLAKE - Query that gets a column sum and aggregates array column

Tags: arrays, group-by, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table like:

```
|------|-------|----------------------|
|  id  |  qty  |      collection      |
|------|-------|----------------------|
| foo  |   2   |    ['foo', 'bar']    |
|------|-------|----------------------|
| foo  |   4   |    ['baz', 'qux']    |
|------|-------|----------------------|
| bar  |   8   |    ['beep', 'boop]   |
|------|-------|----------------------|
```

and I want an output like:

```
|------|-------|------------------------------------|
|  id  |  qty  |      collection                    |
|------|-------|------------------------------------|
| foo  |   6   |    ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux']    |
|------|-------|------------------------------------|
| bar  |   8   |    ['beep', 'boop']                |
|------|-------|------------------------------------|
```

My first attempt was to do something like

```
SELECT
    id, SUM(qty), ARRAY_AGG(collection)
GROUP BY id
```

which gives me the correct qty sum but the array agg is multidimensional array

Doing something like a lateral flatten gives me the correct output array but the sum is off because the flattens array created extra rows with qty.

Comment: I think it was already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57116256/how-to-flatten-a-set-of-array-aggs-in-snowflake-select

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do what you ask

```
with tbl as (select $1 id, $2 qty, parse_json($3) collection from values ('foo',2,'["foo", "bar"]'), ('foo',4,'["baz", "qux"]'), ('bar',8,'["beep", "boop"]'))

select
  id,
  sum(iff(_collection.index=0, qty, 0)),
  array_agg(_collection.value)
from tbl, lateral flatten(collection) _collection
group by id
```